# Android. GradientDrawable setGradientCenter

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I'm trying to make GradientDrawable dynamically change it's gradient center.
I have simple test view, which just draws its background with gradient drawable. Then I wrote such code:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    protected TestView test_view;
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        test_view = (TestView)findViewById(R.id.test_view);
        test_view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                float x = event.getX()/TestView.WND_WIDTH;
                float y = event.getY()/TestView.WND_HEIGHT;
                Log.i("zim32", String.valueOf(x));
                GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable)test_view.getBackground();
                drawable.setGradientCenter(x, y);
                test_view.invalidate();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But gradient center stays at center position... without any movement.. What could be wrong?

Comment: I got the same issue and i am creating a new instance all the time then also it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `view.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);` before this invalidate. It looks like there's no need to do this since you're getting a reference to that already set background drawable and setting a property to it, but if you see the source code behind `View.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);` you'll see that it also sets some flags and so on. For reference: [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.1_r1/android/view/View.java#View.setBackgroundDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)

Another thing to mention - you are setting the initial background drawable someplace else, aren't you? Because if you are not setting the initial background drawable somewhere else, `test_view.getBackground()` will return `null` and you are basically doing nothing. :)

Comment: Thanks. Ye I set drawable in my test view in init() method. Setting setBackgroundDrawable(drawable) to the same drawablehas no effect... But when I create new GradientDrawable() and make setBackgroundDrawable(this_new_gradien) all works.. But it is very bad because I create new object all the time.. Seems to be some kind of caching maybe..